# When do we use static __unsafe_unretained in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I saw this code to define a constant and am having problem understanding the usage.

```
static __unsafe_unretained NSString * const kUserIdKey = @"USER_ID";
```

I am assuming __unsafe_unretained here is the weak without nil out for ios 4 or earlier? It that correct? And why do we need that here?

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially correct in your understanding of `__unsafe_unretained` - such a reference is unmanaged, ARC will simply ignore whatever is stored in the variable.

> And why do we need that here?

You don't, it is meaningless *in this particular example*. Constant `NSString` values are immortal, they will never be collected by ARC. You can annotate `kUserIdKey` with `__strong` or `__weak` or `__unsafe_unretained`  to no effect whatsoever - `@"USER_ID"` will always exist.

Comment: I agree. Worse, this is reliant upon internal behavior of `NSString` which Apple is free to change (albeit, it's extremely unlikely that they ever would).